# How to reuse (native) JPA Query in Spring with container managed EntityManager

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring + JPA (Hibernate), and perform native SQL queries.
The query is built in code, but is always the same, so could be reused.

What I want is to reuse it the same as an old JDBC PreparedStatement would, in the hopes that this gives me some magical performance improvement because the database can reuse an execution plan or something fancy like that.

So my service bean looks something like:

```java
@Service
public class TeaService {

    @Autowired String todaysSecret;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void makeTea(final String teaType) {
       final String querySql = "select tea from table" + todaysSecret + " where type = :teaType";
       entityManager.createNativeQuery(querySql).setParameter("teaType", teaType).executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

And what I want is something like:

```java
@Service
public class TeaService {

    @Autowired String todaysSecret;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Query reusableQuery;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
       final String querySql = "select tea from table" + todaysSecret + " where type = :teaType";
       reusableQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(querySql);
    }

    public void makeTea(final String teaType) {
       reusableQuery.setParameter("teaType", teaType).executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Which might 'work', but as I understand it a Query instances should not live longer then the EntityManager which created them, and the container managed EntityManager injected using @PersistenceContext is actually a proxy, where the container might renew the actual EntityManager.

So what would the correct way to do this be? Is it even possible?
Is there some place in the current 'persistence context' where I can store the query?
Do I need another service/bean/something to manage these reusable queries?
@NamedNativeQuery kinda does what I want, but only allows a single static String, my query is pretty static, but it does need to built programmatically (once). Can I use the same system/storage as those named queries somehow perhaps?

Hope there's someone who actually knows and understands this stuff :)

Thanks!

Comment: You mean sth like [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/define-named-queries-runtime-jpa-2-1/)?

Comment: That looks a lot like what I want :) I'll check if my env is actually JPA 2.1 :)